# "object expected" error JavaScript while calling a function in ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am new to ColdFusion. I am trying to write a JavaScript function to disable a text box based on radio button value. But I am getting "object expected" error while calling the JavaScript function. Please help me out to resolve this problem.

```
<cfscript>
  function validate(){
    alert('hi');
    if(document.report_outage.bkp_dec.checked == true){
      document.report_outage.clbkp_phn.disabled=false;
    }
    else{
      document.report_outage.clbkp_phn.disabled=true;
    }
  }
</cfscript>
<cfset bkp_dec = "Yes,No">

<cfform name="report_outage">
<cfloop list="#bkp_dec#" index="listElement" delimiters=",">
  <cfinput type="radio" name="bkp_dec" value="#listElement#" onclick="validate();"/> <cfoutput>#listElement#</cfoutput> <br>
</cfloop>
<cfinput type="text" name="clbkp_phn" id="clbkp_phn" value=""/>
</cfform>
```

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: I am getting javascript error "Object expected" when i click on the radio button.

Comment: Don't use `cfinput`, use `input` instead. There is no advantage to using `cfinput`.

Answer (score 7):

You are confusing the `<script>` tag and `<cfscript>` tags. `<cfscript>` is used for writing ColdFusion code in cfscript format. If you want to write JavaScript, you need to use the `<script>` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified validate() on onclick which is javascript function and in your code you have specified validate() function under <cfscript> tag which considered as CF code not an javascript.

Just change <cfscript> with <script> and you are done.

Comment: This is a repeat of cfvonner's answer.

Comment: My mistake, I had already + vote to him before I answered. I just tried to elaborate answer since asker was newer to ColdFusion. I think I should need to add into comment instead of seperate answer.